# How detect form submission within Jira Issue Collector?

Tags: iframe, jira, issue-tracking

I have integrated jira issue collector into my Angular application. I need a way to detect when a user submit the feedback so I can send a notification to my team and user regarding the newly created ticket, however since the issue collector is loading inside an iframe I am not able to detect the form submission.

Is there any way to detect from submission inside a cross-origin iframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the notification settings of Jira to notify your team when the ticket is created. This is most likely the best way to handle it.

While it might be possible to get the info inside your angular app, this would be pretty messy and hard to maintain.